# Why can I not copy images from Word document with Word 365 using C# VSTO (null ref exception)?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I have a Word Add-in VSTO program which i've developed. One of the functions that the program does is to check each paragraph in the Word for graphics / images, and if it finds them, copies the image from the paragraph, and saves it to a folder on the user's PC.

The code used to do this is simply:

```
image.Range.Copy();
```

Then to get the image i use:

```
System.Drawing.Image clipboardImage = Clipboard.GetImage();
```

I then save it using:

```
clipboardImage.Save(pathToDirectory);
```

This works without fail on earlier versions of Word, but with 365 (and i think 2013 although not confirmed) it throws a null reference exception when trying to get the image with Clipboard.GetImage();

Anyone know why that might be please? Why might there be an issue with Word 365 (not the browser version but fully installed locally).

Comment: which .net version are you using? and which Visual Studio version?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015, and the application targets .net 4.5

Comment: When asking a question of this nature it would help to have the full code context. It's not clear from what is posted here whether the images belong to the Shapes or InlineShapes collection(s) and how they're being identified in the document content. That's always relevant to working with images in a Word document...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, this is what worked for 365:

```
image.Range.Select();
image.Application.Selection.Copy();

System.Drawing.Image clipboardImage = null;
if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
{
     clipboardImage = Clipboard.GetImage();

     //do something with the image on the clipboard
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comment, you are using Visual Studio 2015 with .Net 4.5

As mentioned [here](https://bettersolutions.com/csharp/office-developer-tools/versions.htm), Office 365 **will only work with Visual Studio 2017 and .Net 4.6.1** (and higher).

Comment: As it turned out, this was not it. I now have VS 2019 and .net 4.7.1 and have the same issue. The image.Range.Copy() returns null (with 365 only.).

Comment: Does it maybe produce some log file or anything that can shed more light on what happened further than return null?

Comment: Since it's an online service I'd check all configurations to make sure the connection to Office 365 authenticates properly.. maybe try calling other methods on the Office 365 file to see if the problem is specific to the Copy() method or something more general

Comment: @Daedalus Please remove the checkmark setting this response as the answer, since it doesn't answer your question. Mark the information you posted as the answer, since it appears to work. Certainly, the Word interop version is totally unrelated to the version of Visual Studio used. This response nonsense for the cited problem in the question...